# Get back state parameter google api sign in

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api

I have a google sign button based on this tutorial https://www.sanwebe.com/2012/11/login-with-google-api-php which works fine.

I am trying to add a state parameter, so I added the line :

```
$client->setState("testingthestate");
```

And this line of code add to the URL : https://....&state=testingthestate

But I can't see how to get back the value of state. Both `$_GET['state']` and `$_POST['state']` are empty!

How to get back the state parameter value ?

Comment: after line 16 in your tutorial you can add your state like `$client->setState($your_state_variable);` than you can get it by `$_GET['state']` when it redirect back.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_GET['state']` in call back function to get state parameter.

Comment: The question explicitly says: "Both $_GET['state'] and $_POST['state'] are empty", so I don't feel like this answer is complete enough, even if it is correct.

Comment: the state parameter is empty because the user is not setting anything in set parameter  $client->setState("testingthestate","Set something");

Comment: @Aniket `setState` function takes only one string parameter.